# KendoWindow .visible(); is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I load the window but set it to visible false, but I cannot set it to be visible after the user clicks on a button.

Here's the code:

Window created during load:

```
 $(function () {
    if (!$("#windowAdmin-Popup").data("kendoWindow")) {
        var windowAdmin = $("#windowAdmin-Popup").kendoWindow({
            actions: ["Close"],
            iframe: false,
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            resizable: true,
            pinned: true,
            open: true,
            visible: false,
            animation: {
                open: {
                    effects: { fadeIn: {} },
                    duration: 200,
                    show: true
                },
                close: {
                    effects: { fadeOut: {} },
                    duration: 600,
                    hide: true
                }
            },
            visible: false,
            title: "",
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                //refreshes grid
                $("#UserProfileGrid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                $("#UserProfileGrid").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
            }
        }).data("kendoWindow");
    }
});
```

This is my onclick func:

```
function addclick() {
    var windowAdmin = $("#windowAdmin-Popup").data("kendoWindow");
   // $("#windowAdmin-Popup")
    windowAdmin.center();
   // $("#windowAdmin-Popup")
    windowAdmin.visible(); //error thrown here
    windowAdmin.refresh({
        url: "/UserManagement/RegisterUser",
        cache: false
    });

 }
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! It was the   open: true line inside the declaration of the kendo window.

Apparently Kendo does not like it if you try and open a window twice ;)